# How to execute some partition step on all servers only once using spring batch partitioning?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am using spring batch partitioning. I read exchanges form files and do some processing for each exchange.

exchanges are distributed over 4 servers to do parallel processing using spring batch partitioning.

I have first step which prepares input files with exchange ids. I need to read these ids on all servers.

Is there any way to run first step on all servers only once to prepare input files on all servers ?

I tried by setting grid size = 4 (number of servers)  and consumer concurrency 1 so that on each server only 1 consumer should listen to step execution request.

The problem is, more that 1 request are handled by 1 consumer so steps run more than once on some servers and so does't run on other servers. The result is data is not prepared on some servers and other steps gets failed.

How can I make sure the step runs on all servers only once ?

Below is the configuration

Import job which has prepareExchangeListJob as first step which should work as explained above and second step importExchanges which is normal partition job. And after importExchanges there are many more steps which are normal partition steps.

```
<job id="importJob">
    <step id="import.prepareExchangesListStep" next="import.importExchangesStep">
        <job ref="prepareExchangesListJob" />
    </step>
    <step id="import.importExchangesStep">
        <job ref="importExchangesJob" />
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="importExchangesStepNotifier" />
        </listeners>
    </step>
</job>
```

PrepareExchangeList job, please note the grid size= 4 (number of servers) and consumer concurrency = 1 so that the step should exectute only once on each server to prepare input data (exchanges) on all servers.

```
<rabbit:template id="prepareExchangesListAmqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" routing-key="prepareExchangesListQueue"
    reply-timeout="${prepare.exchanges.list.step.timeout}">
</rabbit:template>

<int:channel id="prepareExchangesListOutboundChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="prepareExchangesListInboundStagingChannel" />

<amqp:outbound-gateway request-channel="prepareExchangesListOutboundChannel"
    reply-channel="prepareExchangesListInboundStagingChannel"
    amqp-template="prepareExchangesListAmqpTemplate"
    mapped-request-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-reply-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS" />


<beans:bean id="prepareExchangesListMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="prepareExchangesListOutboundChannel"
    p:receiveTimeout="${prepare.exchanges.list.step.timeout}" />


<beans:bean id="prepareExchangesListPartitioner"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.SimplePartitioner"
    scope="step" />


<beans:bean id="prepareExchangesListPartitionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler"
    p:stepName="prepareExchangesListStep" p:gridSize="${prepare.exchanges.list.grid.size}"
    p:messagingOperations-ref="prepareExchangesListMessagingTemplate" />

<int:aggregator ref="prepareExchangesListPartitionHandler"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    send-timeout="${prepare.exchanges.list.step.timeout}"
    input-channel="prepareExchangesListInboundStagingChannel" />

<amqp:inbound-gateway concurrent-consumers="1"
    request-channel="prepareExchangesListInboundChannel" reply-channel="prepareExchangesListOutboundStagingChannel"
    queue-names="prepareExchangesListQueue" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    mapped-request-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-reply-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS" />


<int:channel id="prepareExchangesListInboundChannel" />

<int:service-activator ref="stepExecutionRequestHandler"
    input-channel="prepareExchangesListInboundChannel" output-channel="prepareExchangesListOutboundStagingChannel" />

<int:channel id="prepareExchangesListOutboundStagingChannel" />

<beans:bean id="prepareExchangesFileItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    p:resource="classpath:primary_markets.txt"
    p:lineMapper-ref="stLineMapper" scope="step" />


<beans:bean id="prepareExchangesItemWriter"
    class="com.st.batch.foundation.writers.PrepareExchangesItemWriter"
    p:dirPath="${spring.tmp.batch.dir}/#{jobParameters[batch_id]}" p:numberOfFiles="4" 
    p:symfony-ref="symfonyStepScoped" scope="step" />


<step id="prepareExchangesListStep">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="prepareExchangesFileItemReader" writer="prepareExchangesItemWriter" commit-interval="${prepare.exchanges.commit.interval}"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<job id="prepareExchangesListJob" restartable="true">
    <step id="prepareExchangesListStep.master">
        <partition partitioner="prepareExchangesListPartitioner"
            handler="prepareExchangesListPartitionHandler" />
    </step>
</job>
```

Import Exchanges Job

```
<rabbit:template id="importExchangesAmqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" routing-key="importExchangesQueue"
    reply-timeout="${import.exchanges.partition.timeout}">
</rabbit:template>

<int:channel id="importExchangesOutboundChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="importExchangesInboundStagingChannel" />

<amqp:outbound-gateway request-channel="importExchangesOutboundChannel"
    reply-channel="importExchangesInboundStagingChannel" amqp-template="importExchangesAmqpTemplate"
    mapped-request-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-reply-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="importExchangesOutboundChannel"
    p:receiveTimeout="${import.exchanges.partition.timeout}" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesPartitionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler"
    p:stepName="importExchangesStep" p:gridSize="${import.exchanges.grid.size}"
    p:messagingOperations-ref="importExchangesMessagingTemplate" />

<int:aggregator ref="importExchangesPartitionHandler"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    send-timeout="${import.exchanges.step.timeout}"
    input-channel="importExchangesInboundStagingChannel" />

<amqp:inbound-gateway concurrent-consumers="${import.exchanges.consumer.concurrency}"
    request-channel="importExchangesInboundChannel" reply-channel="importExchangesOutboundStagingChannel"
    queue-names="importExchangesQueue" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    mapped-request-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-reply-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS" />


<int:channel id="importExchangesInboundChannel" />

<int:service-activator ref="stepExecutionRequestHandler"
    input-channel="importExchangesInboundChannel" output-channel="importExchangesOutboundStagingChannel" />

<int:channel id="importExchangesOutboundStagingChannel" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesItemWriter"
    class="com.st.batch.foundation.writers.ImportExchangesAndEclsItemWriter"
    p:symfony-ref="symfonyStepScoped" p:timeout="${import.exchanges.item.timeout}"
    scope="step" />

<beans:bean id="importExchangesPartitioner"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
    p:resources="file:${spring.tmp.batch.dir}/#{jobParameters[batch_id]}/exchanges/exchanges_*.txt"
    scope="step" />

<beans:bean id="importExchangesFileItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    p:resource="#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}" p:lineMapper-ref="stLineMapper"
    scope="step" />

<step id="importExchangesStep">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="importExchangesFileItemReader" writer="importExchangesItemWriter" commit-interval="${import.exchanges.commit.interval}"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<job id="importExchangesJob" restartable="true">
    <step id="importExchangesStep.master">
        <partition partitioner="importExchangesPartitioner"
            handler="importExchangesPartitionHandler" />
    </step>
</job>
```

Comment: Can you describe your job in more detail? Do you have this one prep step and then you want to do normal partitioning on the next step? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting technique.

I would expect the four partitions to be distributed evenly; rabbit typically does round robin distribution to competing consumers (AFAIK). So I am not exactly sure why you're not seeing that behavior.

You could spend some time trying to figure it out, but it's fragile in that you are relying on this; if one of the slaves had a network glitch, its partition would go to one of the others. It would be better to have each slave bind to a different queue and explicitly route the partitions by adding a routing key expression to the (first) outbound gateway...

```
routing-key-expression="'foo.' + headers['sequenceNumber']"
```

and have the slaves listen on `foo.1`, `foo.2` etc., and continue to use a common queue for the second step.

This assumes you are using the default exchange ("") and route by queue name; if you have explicit bindings, you would use those in your routing key expression.

PS: As a reminder you need to increase the `RabbitTemplate` `reply-timeout` if your partitions take more than the default 5 seconds to complete.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed, its not reliable solution, it may not even work if some servers are added at later stage. I need to think of some reliable but efficient solution. Thanks for reminding, but I didnt add reply-timeout to ampq outboudgateway as this property is not there in documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html

Comment: Reading from master over the network may lead to high bandwidth usage and could be slower and so as adding and reading from database.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, it doesn't populates in eclipse, may be its not in namespace as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's in the auto-completion in eclipse for me. Are you using the Spring plugins (or STS)? If so, have you enabled 'spring nature' on the project. If not, you may have to manually populate the eclipse schema cache with the right versions of the schema.

Comment: Thanks I am using STS. will do as you suggested.

Comment: Actually, my mistake - the `reply-timeout` on the gateway is a timeout when sending to the reply channel (in case it's a full queue channel). The default 5 second timeout for the remote reply is on the `RabbitTemplate`. You need to increase the template's `reply-timeout`, not the gateway's.

Comment: Ah ok. I think, creating input files locally on master only and then using spring integration sftp can I copy all the files created in first step to all remote servers? and also if any new server is added later, that can poll to directory on master and get all files copied ?

Comment: Basically, I would like to poll the directory where input files are being create by first step and as soon as files are created, all those files should be copied to all servers. So do I need to use int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter and int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter combination ?

Comment: Actually, it's probable easier to use the `stfp:outbound-gateway` and use a `mget` command (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) to fetch the files during the first partition from the "second" step - if (files not yet fetched for this job) {mget} - you could pass the master hostname in the step execution context.

Comment: Thanks, why do we need this ToSftpFlowGateway class? or just the gateway configuration should work ? I just need to download all files from remote server directory recursively to local directory.

Comment: Just tried sftp:outbound-gateway but having some problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364937/how-to-download-files-from-remote-server-using-spring-integration-sftp-outbound