# How to download files from remote server using spring integration sftp outbound gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-batch-admin

I have spring batch setup (remote partitioning), which reads items from files and process them.

If input file do not exist, I want to copy them from remote server. So I have added a step listener in that I am trying to download files from remote server using spring integration sftp outbound gateway.

```
public class PrepareExchangeListListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    private String localDir;
    private String remoteDir;

    private DirectChannel requestChannel;
    private PollableChannel replyChannel;

    public String getLocalDir() {
        return localDir;
    }

    public void setLocalDir(String localDir) {
        this.localDir = localDir;
    }

    public String getRemoteDir() {
        return remoteDir;
    }

    public void setRemoteDir(String remoteDir) {
        this.remoteDir = remoteDir;
    }

    public DirectChannel getRequestChannel() {
        return requestChannel;
    }

    public void setRequestChannel(DirectChannel requestChannel) {
        this.requestChannel = requestChannel;
    }

    public PollableChannel getReplyChannel() {
        return replyChannel;
    }

    public void setReplyChannel(PollableChannel replyChannel) {
        this.replyChannel = replyChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Listener triggered.");

        this.requestChannel.send(new GenericMessage<Object>(this.remoteDir
                + "/" + "*"));

        Message<?> result = this.replyChannel.receive(100000);

        List<File> localFiles = (List<File>) result.getPayload();

        for (File file : localFiles) {

            System.out.println(file.getName());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

I am referring to this test case

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound/SftpOutboundTests.java

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound/SftpServerOutboundTests-context.xml

Below is my configuration,

```
<rabbit:template id="importExchangesAmqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" routing-key="importExchangesQueue"
    reply-timeout="${import.exchanges.partition.timeout}">
</rabbit:template>

<int:channel id="importExchangesOutboundChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="importExchangesInboundStagingChannel" />

<amqp:outbound-gateway request-channel="importExchangesOutboundChannel"
    reply-channel="importExchangesInboundStagingChannel" amqp-template="importExchangesAmqpTemplate"
    mapped-request-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-reply-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="importExchangesOutboundChannel"
    p:receiveTimeout="${import.exchanges.partition.timeout}" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesPartitionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler"
    p:stepName="importExchangesStep" p:gridSize="${import.exchanges.grid.size}"
    p:messagingOperations-ref="importExchangesMessagingTemplate" />

<int:aggregator ref="importExchangesPartitionHandler"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" send-timeout="${import.exchanges.step.timeout}"
    input-channel="importExchangesInboundStagingChannel" />

<amqp:inbound-gateway concurrent-consumers="${import.exchanges.consumer.concurrency}"
    request-channel="importExchangesInboundChannel" reply-channel="importExchangesOutboundStagingChannel"
    queue-names="importExchangesQueue" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    mapped-request-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-reply-headers="correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize, STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS" />


<int:channel id="importExchangesInboundChannel" />

<int:service-activator ref="stepExecutionRequestHandler"
    input-channel="importExchangesInboundChannel" output-channel="importExchangesOutboundStagingChannel" />

<int:channel id="importExchangesOutboundStagingChannel" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesItemWriter"
    class="com.st.batch.foundation.writers.ImportExchangesAndEclsItemWriter"
    p:symfony-ref="symfonyStepScoped" p:timeout="${import.exchanges.item.timeout}"
    scope="step" />

<beans:bean id="importExchangesPartitioner"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
    p:resources="file:${spring.tmp.batch.dir}/#{jobParameters[batch_id]}/exchanges/exchanges_*.txt"
    scope="step" />

<beans:bean id="importExchangesFileItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    p:resource="#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}" p:lineMapper-ref="stLineMapper"
    scope="step" />




<beans:bean id="prepareExchangeListListener"
    class="com.st.batch.listeners.PrepareExchangeListListener"
    p:requestChannel-ref="inboundMGetRecursiveFiltered" p:localDir="/tmp/spring/batch"
    p:replyChannel-ref="outputSftp" p:remoteDir="/tmp/spring/batch" />

<beans:bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <beans:property name="host" value="myRemoteServer" />
    <beans:property name="user" value="username" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>

<int:channel id="outputSftp">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>


<int:channel id="inboundMGetRecursiveFiltered" />

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inboundMGetRecursiveFiltered" command="mget"
    expression="payload" command-options="-R" local-directory="/tmp/spring/batch"
    reply-channel="outputSftp" />


<step id="importExchangesStep">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="importExchangesFileItemReader" writer="importExchangesItemWriter"
            commit-interval="${import.exchanges.commit.interval}" />
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="prepareExchangeListListener" />
    </listeners>


    </tasklet>

</step>

<job id="importExchangesJob" restartable="true">
    <step id="importExchangesStep.master">
        <partition partitioner="importExchangesPartitioner"
            handler="importExchangesPartitionHandler" />

    <listeners>
        <listener ref="prepareExchangeListListener" />
    </listeners>
    </step>
</job>
```

Am I doing anything wrong as nothing seems to be working.

Also, can int-sftp:outbound-gateway have scope="step" ? If I try to add, it gives error in STS.

Log

Here is a log with DEBUG level enabled

```
19:42:18,329  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Connecting to SERVER_IP port 22
19:42:18,473  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Connection established
19:42:18,623  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
19:42:18,623  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.45
19:42:18,624  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
19:42:18,668  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes256-ctr is not available.
19:42:18,668  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes192-ctr is not available.
19:42:18,668  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes256-cbc is not available.
19:42:18,669  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes192-cbc is not available.
19:42:18,669  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - arcfour256 is not available.
19:42:18,669  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
19:42:18,673  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
19:42:18,673  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
19:42:18,767  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
19:42:18,767  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
19:42:18,767  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
19:42:18,778  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
19:42:18,778  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
19:42:18,935  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
19:42:18,938  WARN jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:55 - Permanently added 'SERVER_IP' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
19:42:18,939  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
19:42:18,939  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
19:42:18,945  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
19:42:19,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:19,088  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
19:42:19,918  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
19:42:19,918  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Next authentication method: publickey
19:42:19,919  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Authentications that can continue: password
19:42:19,920  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Next authentication method: password
19:42:20,001 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:20,084  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Authentication succeeded (password).
19:42:20,542 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 util.SimplePool:184 - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@7d4d6823.
19:42:21,001 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:21,134 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 session.CachingSessionFactory:109 - Releasing Session back to the pool.
19:42:21,134 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 util.SimplePool:215 - Releasing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@7d4d6823 back to the pool
19:42:21,134 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 gateway.SftpOutboundGateway:197 - handler 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0' sending reply Message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403532741134, id=e4f6e7b3-b8bf-4364-99b4-ca889e5aa7fa, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
19:42:21,135 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.QueueChannel:224 - preSend on channel 'outputSftp', message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403532741134, id=e4f6e7b3-b8bf-4364-99b4-ca889e5aa7fa, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
19:42:21,135 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.QueueChannel:237 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'outputSftp', message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403532741134, id=e4f6e7b3-b8bf-4364-99b4-ca889e5aa7fa, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
19:42:21,135 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.DirectChannel:237 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inboundMGetRecursiveFiltered', message: [Payload=/tmp/spring/batch/*][Headers={timestamp=1403532738315, id=334c6d05-be25-4a9b-b9d8-773103da1cfd, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch, file_remoteFile=*.txt}]
19:42:21,135 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.QueueChannel:258 - postReceive on channel 'outputSftp', message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403532741134, id=e4f6e7b3-b8bf-4364-99b4-ca889e5aa7fa, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
19:42:21,193 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 scope.StepScope:108 - Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.importExchangesPartitioner
19:42:21,193 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:435 - Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.importExchangesPartitioner'
19:42:21,204 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 scope.StepScope:136 - Registered destruction callback in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.importExchangesPartitioner
19:42:21,204 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.importExchangesPartitioner'
19:42:22,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:23,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:24,001 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:25,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:26,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:42:27,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

Full log here

http://pastebin.com/4KDBGqCH

UPDATE:

Below is just a simple test instead of entire use case,

Test job

```
<beans:bean id="testStepTasklet"
    class="com.sta.batch.foundation.tasklets.TestTasklet"
    p:requestChannel-ref="inboundMGetRecursive" p:replyChannel-ref="output" />

<job id="testJob">
    <step id="testStep">
        <tasklet ref="testStepTasklet" />
    </step>
</job>
```

sftp oubound gateway configuration

```
<beans:bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <beans:property name="host" value="MY_SERVER_ID" />
    <beans:property name="user" value="myUser" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="myPassword" />
</beans:bean>


<int:channel id="output">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="inboundMGetRecursive" />

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inboundMGetRecursive" command="mget" expression="payload"
    command-options="-R" local-directory="/tmp/spring/batch/"
    reply-channel="output" />
```

TestTasklet

```
public class TestTasklet implements Tasklet, InitializingBean {

    private DirectChannel requestChannel;
    private PollableChannel replyChannel;

    public DirectChannel getRequestChannel() {
        return requestChannel;
    }

    public void setRequestChannel(DirectChannel requestChannel) {
        this.requestChannel = requestChannel;
    }

    public PollableChannel getReplyChannel() {
        return replyChannel;
    }

    public void setReplyChannel(PollableChannel replyChannel) {
        this.replyChannel = replyChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
            ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        String dir = "/tmp/spring/batch/";
        this.requestChannel.send(new GenericMessage<Object>(dir + "*"));
        Message<?> result = this.replyChannel.receive(1000);

        List<File> localFiles = (List<File>) result.getPayload();

        for (File file : localFiles) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;

    }

}
```

Log:

```
12:30:50,017 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 context.StepContextRepeatCallback:76 - Chunk execution starting: queue size=0
12:30:50,025 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.DirectChannel:224 - preSend on channel 'inboundMGetRecursive', message: [Payload=/tmp/spring/batch/*][Headers={timestamp=1403593250024, id=7080f48d-6b7d-4d31-b0b8-b3384dc93e53}]
12:30:50,025 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 gateway.SftpOutboundGateway:67 - org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0 received message: [Payload=/tmp/spring/batch/*][Headers={timestamp=1403593250024, id=7080f48d-6b7d-4d31-b0b8-b3384dc93e53}]
12:30:50,038  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Connecting to SERVER_IP port 22
12:30:50,181  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Connection established
12:30:50,332  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
12:30:50,333  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.45
12:30:50,333  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
12:30:50,376  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes256-ctr is not available.
12:30:50,377  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes192-ctr is not available.
12:30:50,377  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes256-cbc is not available.
12:30:50,377  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - aes192-cbc is not available.
12:30:50,377  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - arcfour256 is not available.
12:30:50,377  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
12:30:50,381  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
12:30:50,382  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
12:30:50,477  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
12:30:50,477  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
12:30:50,477  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
12:30:50,489  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
12:30:50,489  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
12:30:50,645  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
12:30:50,647  WARN jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:55 - Permanently added 'SERVER_IP' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
12:30:50,648  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
12:30:50,648  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
12:30:50,651  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
12:30:50,794  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
12:30:50,964  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
12:30:50,964  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Next authentication method: publickey
12:30:50,966  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Authentications that can continue: password
12:30:50,966  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Next authentication method: password
12:30:51,001 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
12:30:51,126  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 jcraft.jsch:52 - Authentication succeeded (password).
12:30:51,581 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 util.SimplePool:184 - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@329c5e61.
12:30:52,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
12:30:52,160 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 session.CachingSessionFactory:109 - Releasing Session back to the pool.
12:30:52,160 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 util.SimplePool:215 - Releasing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@329c5e61 back to the pool
12:30:52,161 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 gateway.SftpOutboundGateway:197 - handler 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0' sending reply Message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403593252160, id=00899cf1-5dd7-4192-b0ae-9812fe07283e, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
12:30:52,161 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.QueueChannel:224 - preSend on channel 'output', message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403593252160, id=00899cf1-5dd7-4192-b0ae-9812fe07283e, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
12:30:52,161 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.QueueChannel:237 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'output', message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403593252160, id=00899cf1-5dd7-4192-b0ae-9812fe07283e, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
12:30:52,162 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.DirectChannel:237 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inboundMGetRecursive', message: [Payload=/tmp/spring/batch/*][Headers={timestamp=1403593250024, id=7080f48d-6b7d-4d31-b0b8-b3384dc93e53}]
12:30:52,162 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 channel.QueueChannel:258 - postReceive on channel 'output', message: [Payload=[]][Headers={timestamp=1403593252160, id=00899cf1-5dd7-4192-b0ae-9812fe07283e, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/spring/batch/, file_remoteFile=*}]
12:30:52,162 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 tasklet.TaskletStep:433 - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
12:30:52,164 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 tasklet.TaskletStep:447 - Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=371, version=1, name=testStep, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
12:30:52,283 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.RepeatTemplate:437 - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
12:30:52,284 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 step.AbstractStep:212 - Step execution success: id=371
12:30:52,383 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 step.AbstractStep:276 - Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=371, version=3, name=testStep, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0
12:30:52,432 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.SimpleFlow:175 - Completed state=testJob.testStep with status=COMPLETED
12:30:52,433 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.SimpleFlow:161 - Handling state=testJob.end1
12:30:52,433 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.SimpleFlow:175 - Completed state=testJob.end1 with status=COMPLETED
12:30:52,434 DEBUG jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 job.AbstractJob:305 - Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=91, version=1, startTime=Tue Jun 24 12:30:49 IST 2014, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Tue Jun 24 12:30:49 IST 2014, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=91, version=0, Job=[testJob]], jobParameters=[{b=6, batch_id=2014-06-14}]
12:30:52,457  INFO jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1 support.SimpleJobLauncher:136 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=testJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{b=6, batch_id=2014-06-14}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
12:30:53,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
12:30:54,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
12:30:55,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
12:30:56,001 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
12:30:57,000 DEBUG task-scheduler-3 endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter:71 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break things down into manageable chunks - get the SFTP stuff working in a stand-alone test; then assemble it into your job.

Turn on DEBUG logging to see what's happening with the gateway.

No, you can't put Spring Integration components into `Step` Scope, you would have to create it programmatically or in a child context as shown in the (dynamic ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp).

Comment: Thanks, will try creating stand alone example. Updated DEBUG level log, just not receiving reply messages. will try though.

Comment: Tried with simple test job, but same problem. I followed sample exactly with just local directory parameter different, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does it not work with old spring integration version ? I am using spring batch admin which uses spring integration 2.2.5 ?

Comment: Yes, it is because of old version of spring integration used by spring batch admin (2.2.5). I just tested the same sample example with latest spring integration version 4.0.2, it works fine. If i upgrade it in pom, spring batch admin breaks !

Comment: The recursive (`-R`) option was [added in 3.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/history.html#3.0-(s)ftp-changes), you can only fetch from a single directory with 2.2. Spring Batch Integration was moved from Spring Batch Admin to Spring Batch in 3.0.0 and uses Spring Integration 4.0.x.

Comment: Thanks, I need to use -R option. Though spring  batch uses integration 4.0.x. spring batch admin doesn't seems to be moved since then.

Comment: I don't know the status of spring batch admin; I will try to find out. You should be able to use Spring Integration 3.0.2 with the older batch admin (3.0.x includes the `-R` option).

Comment: got response from spring batch team, they have upgraded integration version to 3.0.x but changes will be released in spring  batch admin 1.3 release. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/commit/5f819481deabfc45ef86cff8b3b66c50419eef0d#commitcomment-6779980 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM-188